# Can I remote into Windows 8 non-enterprise edition?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-8.1

I am looking at a [comparison](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/windows-8-1/compare/default.aspx) between Windows 8.1 and Windows 8.1 Enterprise and it says that Windows 8.1 cannot act as a Remote Host.  Does that mean that I can't remote into it?

Comment: That is indeed correct.  If you want that ability purchase `Windows 8.1 Professional`

Comment: You can always use TeamViewer or other such non-Windows remote services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct, you must purchase either Windows 8.1 Pro or 8.1 Enterprise if you want to use Microsoft Remote Desktop and have the computer act as the host (the destination).

However there are other solutions out there that will work instead, for example [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) or [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/) both provide solutions that allow you to remotely connect to the computer and works on standard edition of Windows.